# Symfony4 multiple guard authenticator redirect problem

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, firewall

For my Symfony4 app, I would like :

- 1 firewall for middle-office
- 1 firewall for back-office.

Sounded good to have one dedicated Guard authenticator for each (especially for redirect after login, get login page...). I used `make` to create guard files boilerplate, and I ended up to files below.

While login in middle-office works straightfully, I keep having a redirect loop when I try to go to `/admin` part.

Logs show that `admin` firewall is correctly catched as the good one here, but although I put `app_admin_login` OK for anonymous access, **it keeps redirecting to entry point** which is `admin/login`. Why so?

I surely miss somehting here, thanks for your enlightments.

```
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] request.INFO: Matched route "easyadmin". {"route":"easyadmin","route_parameters":{"_controller":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction","path":"/admin/","permanent":true,"scheme":null,"httpPort":8900,"httpsPort":443,"_route":"easyadmin"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8900/admin","method":"GET"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticators":1} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:51)"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []

[2019-02-13 11:46:39] request.INFO: Matched route "app_admin_login". {"route":"app_admin_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_admin_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::adminLogin"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8900/admin/login","method":"GET"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticators":1} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:51)"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []

[2019-02-13 11:46:39] request.INFO: Matched route "app_admin_login". {"route":"app_admin_login","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_admin_login","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::adminLogin"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8900/admin/login","method":"GET"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticators":1} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"admin","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.INFO: An AuthenticationException was thrown; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code: 0): A Token was not found in the TokenStorage. at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:51)"} []
[2019-02-13 11:46:39] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
... Until max loop iteration number reached
```

security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Shop\User:
            algorithm: argon2i

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Shop\User
                property: email
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator
#            logout_on_user_change: true
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
#            logout_on_user_change: true

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

AdminLoginFormAuthenticator

```
class AdminLoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    private $request;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        return ('app_admin_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route'))
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('easyadmin'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_admin_login');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the file created by the make-command? If so, could you show the code for the AdminLoginFormAuthenticator?

Comment: I can't exactly tell why without seeing the code, but apparently Your AdminAuthenticator does not support the request, as can be seen by the log message: "Guard authenticator does not support the request.". If you check the [make-template](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/blob/master/src/Resources/skeleton/authenticator/LoginFormAuthenticator.tpl.php#L39-L43) the route is hardcoded and likely does not match your admin_login-route

Comment: @dbrumann I added the AdminLoginFormAuthenticator. The message about Guard not concerned is not the explanation to me because this appear on the GET requet to display login. For me this message come from the POST condition in the support method.

Comment: As a complement, I should say that if I restrict the pattern to `^/admin$` remove the loop, but login is not working and log seems show that admin firewall is not triggered each time.

Comment: I will take a look at it later. From quickly glancing at it, I can't see the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I would be interested by any lead that could help me get it right.

Comment: So, I can reproduce the issue and it seems to be related to `start()` in the abstract class which the authenticators extend. It uses the `getLoginUrl()` to redirect and when I change the AdminAuthenticators url to `app_login` it displays that form, but with `admin_login` it will loop forever. I have no idea yet why, but maybe you want to use that as a starting point for debugging it yourself

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @dbrumann who pointed me in right direction, I managed to make a workaround.
It's a workaround only as it doesn't explain the redirection itself but **avoid it**.

I overrided the `AbstratcFormLoginAuthenticator::start()` method to this :

```
/**
     * Overrided to avoid redirection loop
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationException|null $authException
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = $this->getLoginUrl();

        // If URL different than login one, redirect to login one
        if($url !== $this->urlGenerator->generate($request->attributes->get('_route'))) {
            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
        // Render login page as a subrequest for this call only
        else {
            $path['_controller'] = SecurityController::class . '::adminLogin';
            $subRequest = $request->duplicate([], null, $path);

            return $this->kernel->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Redirect to `admin/login` page is effective, `admin` firewall is calles, admin guard respond and login successful redirect on admin part.

Comment: Thanks I had this exact same issue in Symfony 4.4 and this work around worked for me.